# How to deserialize this using GSON? (get rid of List<StringMap>)

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I have jsons like:

```
{ 
    "id":  "AnId",
    "type": "Button",
    "parameter": {
        "text" : "TestText"
    }
}
```

parameters can be of any structure and they can contain further json objects or arrays, too, e.g:

```
{ 
    "id":  "AnId",
    "type": "RadioGroup",
    "parameter": {
         "groupname": "AGroupName",
         "selected": "r2",
         "radioboxes": [
              {
                   "id": "r1",
                   "label": "radio1"
              },
              {
                   "id": "r2",
                   "label": "radio2"
              }
         ]
    }
}
```

However, depending on the type, it is known what the parameters look like, e.g.

```java
public class RadioGroup {
    private String groupName;
    // ..other primitive attributes here..
    private Map<String, RadioBox> radioBoxes;
    // ... getters/setters
}

public class RadioBox {
  private String id;

  private String label;
  // ... getter/setters
}
```

BUT I don't know the type before I deserialized it!

I wonder what is the best way to deserialize input where I dont know whether I get button or radiogroup json?

Until now I just deserialize the given input (button or checkbox, not known yet) to `Map<String, Object>`, if it is in fact button it works fine, but if I provide the radiogroup as input, I will get gson's internal type `ArrayList<StringMap>` for the radioboxes. The primitive parameters like groupName are fine (`String.class`). But what can I do to get `List<Map<String,Radiobox>>` instead of `ArrayList<StringMap>` for the radioboxes parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Type of the custom class you're using. This is for serialising (just an example):

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create()
    Type aType = new TypeToken</ClassName/>() {}.getType();     
    String json = gson.toJson(this, aType);
```

gson will then convert the variable types correctly. If you're using a *custom class* as a variable, you'll need to write a custom type adapter and register the type adapter with the `GsonBuilder()` instance.

To deserialise, you'll need the same process.

**EDIT**:

```
    Class<?> klass = null;
    try {
        klass = Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new JsonParseException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Well, I don't know the TypeToken before deserializing the input because I don't know if I have a button-json or a radiobox-json. That's what my question is about: how can I provide gson with the information how to deserialize then? I of course could parse the type and then do a huge switch but that is awkward to maintain and I hope that there is a more elegant way of achieving my goal.

Comment: Hnnngh, I'd implement a `getClass()` of your own to avoid reflection perhaps (in each of the classes)?

Failing that, reflection. People seem to hate it, but it's a reasonable solution to serialisation/deserialisation of abstract types, I feel.

Comment: I still do not get how this solves my problem. I tried to make more explicit what my problem is.

Comment: Ahh, apologies, I didn't read through my code correctly. You'd need to create a type adapter and have it write the class name to the json output. When you read it back in (i.e. deserialising) you can create the class (in the type adapter) based on that string.  Look at `JsonElement serialize()` and `JsonElement deserialize()` - you'll need to use reflection to determine the class type. Updated answer above with reflection example.

Comment: I cannot influence the format of the input!! I only need to deserialize it.

Comment: Then you'll definitely need a custom type adapter. Work out what JSON you're reading, see if it matches a RadioGroup, Box or whatever, and create that class type.

Maybe use a case statement instead of multiple if blocks.

Comment: Custom deserializer is the way I do it now. Just wondered if there are built-in methods for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can parse arbitrary json using GSON JsonDeserializer. I've write model class for RadioGroup as following but you can change it according to your need.

```
public class RadioGroup {
  private String id;
  private String type;
  // You can put groupName and selected properties into other class, 
  private String groupname;
  private String selected;
  // for button param parsing into Map
  private Map<String,String> btnParam;
  // for radion Btn just parsing into List
  private List<RadioBox> radioboxes;
}

public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RadioGroup> {

        @Override
        public RadioGroup deserialize(JsonElement json, Type arg1,
                JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {

            final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            final String id= jsonObject.get("id").getAsString();
            final String type= jsonObject.get("type").getAsString();
            final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup();

            radioGroup.setId(id);
            radioGroup.setType(type);

            JsonElement jsonElementForParam = jsonObject.get("parameter");
            JsonElement jsonElementForText = jsonElementForParam.getAsJsonObject().get("text");

            if(null==jsonElementForText){
                String groupname = jsonElementForParam.getAsJsonObject().get("groupname").getAsString();
                String selected = jsonElementForParam.getAsJsonObject().get("selected").getAsString();
                JsonElement jsonElementForRadioboxes = jsonElementForParam.getAsJsonObject().get("radioboxes");

                radioGroup.setSelected(selected);
                radioGroup.setGroupname(groupname);

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type typeOf = new TypeToken<List<RadioBox>>(){}.getType();  
                List<RadioBox> radioboxes =gson.fromJson(jsonElementForRadioboxes, typeOf);
                radioGroup.setRadioboxes(radioboxes);


            } else if (null!=jsonElementForText) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type typeOf = new TypeToken<Map<String,String>>(){}.getType();  
                Map<String,String> map = gson.fromJson(jsonElementForParam, typeOf);
                radioGroup.setBtnParam(map);

            }

            return radioGroup;
        }
      }
```

Finally Parse it

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
   gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(RadioGroup.class, new CustomDeserializer());
   Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
   RadioGroup radioGroup = gson.fromJson(buttonJson, RadioGroup.class);
```

Comment: That would fail if the input is button.json because buttons do neither have "radioboxes" nor "groupname" nor "selected" keys, but "text". The input is arbitrary! I dont now the type before the serialization as I wrote in my question.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this solution does not scale! Think of 100 different element types, and future requirements might need even more. You would put all that in one class? No way! However, I wrote a custom Deserializer to deserialize the type and depending on it I can delegate the deserialization to a type-specific deserializer for each type. I'm just wondering if there is a nicer "built-in" way, so I'll let the question open.